# Is the word "homophone" misleading?

Tags: pronunciation, spoken-english, homophones

I remember a language learning app that claimed to help users to distinguish between the words like right-write, break-brake, heal-heel, principle-principal, etc.

However, I have long known them as homophones. This leads me to a question : Is the word "homophone" misleading? If one can distinguish between the said words, they should not be called homophones.

Comment: Curious: did it claim to teach you how to distinguish them _by sound_ or _by context_?

Comment: *homophone* means that they ***sound*** the same; they can still be distinguished contextually and orthographically

Comment: Now I'm curious: what did you think *homophone* means?

Comment: @jonathanjo By sound.

Comment: @AntonSherwood I have always known homophones as words that have different spellings but same pronunciation.

Comment: Do the pairs that you listed not fit that definition?

Answer (score 7):

These words are homophones.  If you are attempting to distinguish them *by sound* you will fail, as there is no difference in sound  (there may be differences in some dialects, but none that I am aware of)

So these words are homophones. They have the same sound (but different meanings)

It is appropriate to call these words homophones. You can distinguish only by semantic context and by the grammatical function of the word. Genuine confusion is rare.

Comment: It's just worth reminding that pronunciation is not uniform, and "homophone" has to be understood relative to a particular accent or group of accents.  For example, in Scottish English, "loch" is /lɒx/ and "lock" is /lɒk/; in many English and American accents, both are /lɒk/.  In general though, "homophone" would be understood to mean "homophone in most or all common accents".  All of the original examples would be homophones in standard BrE and AmE and every accent I know of.